# Using auth0 on AWS EC2 in a Shiny app using RStudio

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, authentication

I am trying to use `auth0` on AWS EC2 (Ubuntu) using RStudio using the R package - [auth0](https://github.com/curso-r/auth0). To make the Shiny app publicly accessible, I have the port 8100 (this is where the app is hosted) open to the public.

Further, I am using the `options(shiny.host="xx.xx.xx.xx")` to specify the **public** IP address of the EC2 machine in RStudio. When I run the shiny app through the "Run App" button in RStudio I get this error:

```
Listening on http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8100
createTcpServer: address not available
Error in .subset2(public_bind_env, "initialize")(...) : 
 Failed to create server
```

I have similar settings for `auth0` as I had on my local machine which works fine.

The auth0.yml file that I use is as under:

```
name: myApp
shiny_config: xx.xx.xx.xx:8100
auth0_config:
  scope: "openid email profile"
  api_url: !expr paste0('https://', Sys.getenv('AUTH0_USER'), '.auth0.com')
  credentials:
    key: !expr Sys.getenv("AUTH0_KEY")
    secret: !expr Sys.getenv("AUTH0_SECRET")
```

Any suggestions to debug the issue are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EC2 instances don’t have their *public IP* addresses configured on their network interfaces. Hence they can’t listen on them. You’ll have to configure your app to listen on the *private IP* (check `ip addr show eth0`) or leave it blank and it should listen on all available local addrs.

The translation from *public* to the *private* IP is done by AWS outside of the instance.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: This worked for me, I specified the *private* IP in the `options(shiny.host = ...)` and this can be accessed from outside using the *public* IP. Therefore all the external services like `auth0.com` only need to see the *public* IP which gets auto-translated by AWS to the *private* IP for internal use.